# build dll file from xlslib

Tags: c++, dll, xlslib

I need to download `xlslib` and build dll file for windows.

I downladed the xlslib repository.

I think it has to be in `c++`.

what should I do?
please help me!

Answer (score 2):

Open the solution file for the MS Visual Studio version you have, e.g. `xlslib\xlslib\msvc2012\xlslib.sln`, then choose the project **xlslib_dll**, select the configuration you want (probably **Win32 Debug** or **Win32 Release**) and run the build. If all goes well, it will create the DLL and LIB files you want.

If you don't have MS Visual Studio, you can easily install the free (even for commercial use nowadays) [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34673).

Comment: Depends on what do you mean by the exe file. xlslib is just a library which other .exe programs can use to do their stuff. The only application you can build this way seems to be some unit tests for the library.

Comment: the instructions that I got:
build xlslib to dll
download xlslib from sourceforg
build it to windows

you need to submit exe and dll file

Comment: Then you need some more information what the exe file should do, like "load this data and store it into Excel sheet". You managed to build the library which contains all the functions to create .xls files, but there is nothing about what they want to accomplish with it in the instructions.